# Not able to click on dropdown menu where each option is a radio button, using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having trouble in WebDriver in selecting an option from dropdown where options are of `type=radio` as shown below:

```
<input id="ui-multiselect-companyListSelect-option-2" type="radio" title=" Display Deleted " value="deleted" name="multiselect_companyListSelect" aria-selected="true">
<span> Display Deleted </span>
```

I am using following XPath expression:

```
selectDisplayDeleted = //input[@name='multiselect_companyListSelect']/../span[text()=' Display Deleted '] and executing selectDisplayDeleted.click() on this element.
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: f667a12c7452cc7d9cf69a07523f1ed4
Build info: version: '2.36.0', revision: '9b50f805d0a53506a5ee6a55be8669f106d8d34e', time: '2013-10-17 11:09:21'
System info: host: 'gc-wk-rbah-01', ip: '10.10.20.75', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:327)
    at $Proxy2.click(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.click(EventFiringWebDriver.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a two click step. First on the dropdown and then on the option value. In your case based on the xpath you provided, the first click will be on the element input[@name='multiselect_companyListSelect'] and then the option value.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm your XPath looks a bit too lax to me, it might be better to use the `following-sibling` or `preceding-sibling` axes to get at the `span`. Also there seems to be some whitespace in your span text that could be causing an issue?

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Display Deleted'][preceding-sibling::input/@name eq 'multiselect_companyListSelect']
```